# JRuby - disable Apache Common Logging

Tags: apache, logging, jruby

I'm trying to disable Apache Common Logging in JRuby this way:

```
require 'java'
...

module ...

  java_import org.apache.commons.logging.Log
  java_import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

  java::lang.static {
    java::lang.System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", 
                                  "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog")
  }
```

based on Java code:

```
static {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
                       "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
}
```

In Java above code disables logging but in JRuby logging is still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

the `java::lang.static` just does nothing (it works since JRuby needs to lazily allow package names since it can not know before-hand which packages will exists until a class is loaded from a given package).

in Ruby and thus JRuby there's no static initializers - code is executed as it's parsed thus simply do a (no need for the java_imports neither since you're not using those classes) :

`java::lang.System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", 
                               "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog")`